# In Chromoscope, what is the X-ray source between Ophiuchus, Libra and Scorpius?

Tags: light, milky-way, spectra, x-ray

[Chromoscope](http://www.chromoscope.net/) is a nice toy. Pressing 'L' shows the constellations as guide.

There's a bright X-ray source between Ophiuchus, Libra and Scorpius. In Hydrogen-Alpha there are two circular formations to the right and left of it. Are the latter formed by polar jets from the former, and what is that object?

Comment: I haven't found any info yet, but it looks more like  a prominent X-ray source surrounded by a disk that's absorbing the X-rays. I'm guessing that black means no X-rays, but there's so much background noise it's hard to get a baseline.

Comment: Assuming that that thing *is* a disk, I wouldn't think those formations are related, because they're at odd angles - they're not on the same level as the disk, but they're not coming from the poles, either. They seem to be related to nearby stars - see how they're centered around stars? They're not unique to this object.

Comment: Guess #1: [Scorpius X-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorpius_X-1).

Comment: @HDE226868 At the huge distance of Scorpius X-1, the three formations can't be related. Please make it an answer, if you're sure ;-)

Comment: I'm far from sure. . . I'm fairly certain the formations aren't related, though.

Comment: @HDE226868 Three dots almost on a line, and I have a hypothesis! That's why I'm not an astronomer. (But I can make up new constellations, if someone wants some...)

Comment: I essentially reworked my answer, for the record.

Comment: @HDE226868 it looks like a great answer, but it's currently deleted

Answer (score 2):

The source *is* Sco X-1. It is a point source of X-rays.

I'll have get back to you on why it looks that way in chromoscope, but it looks incorrect to me.